# Image overlapping on a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

The issue that I face is:

1. I have created a dynamic button in a linear layout with vertical orientation in the center of a relative layout.
2. Then, I want to add an image on top of the linear layout which show at the right bottom of the first button.

However, after struggling for 2 days, I still couldn't get it right. The "Image" is displaying at the center of the the first button.

The image that i want the application to be.

[image]

This is the particular code:

```
///outermost layout
RelativeLayout L1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
L1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

//For image overlapping on linear layout
FrameLayout FrameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams RelativeParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

//Place all dynamic button inside here -vertical
LinearLayout L2 = new LinearLayout(this);
L2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
L2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

ImageView handpointer;
handpointer = new ImageView(this);

//grab the imageview and load the animations
handpointer.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hand));
```

This is the code where all the dynamic button add in the Layout L2.

```
    L2.addView(b);
    L2.addView(b);
}

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Param.setMargins(0, 70, 0, 0);
L1.addView(FrameLayout,Param);

Param.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
FrameLayout.addView(L2,Param);
RelativeParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
FrameLayout.addView(handpointer);

Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.snail_menu); 
L1.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

this.setContentView(L1);
```

Really thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you not using XML to design your layout?

Comment: I didnt use XML because i have my button dynamically.

Comment: You can do that using XML also. Even it'll be easier for you.

Comment: Where is the problematic image in the code?

Comment: I wana add the image but it seems that i dont have enough credit to post it. TT

Comment: Can i know how to add it in XML even if it is a dynamically added button?

Comment: Sergey Glotov : i have put in the image that i wana show.

Answer (score 0):

Place your button in XML, wherever you want to display it at run-time. And just use `setVisibility` method to display or hide it. Isn't it the feasible solution ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can i have any example on it?

Comment: Refer to this demo example : http://www.ceveni.com/2009/07/switching-between-layouts-in-android.html. Here it is dealing with layouts, similarly you can use btn.setVisibility(View.GONE) or btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE).

Comment: Also to achieve desired result, you need to go in a trial and error method until you get your exact layout for your activity.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for your dynamic view creation , it may help you

///outermost layout

```
RelativeLayout L1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
L1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

//For image overlapping on linear layout

```
FrameLayout FrameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams RelativeParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

//Place all dynamic button inside here -vertical

```
TableLayout TL = new TableLayout(this);
TL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

ImageView handpointer;
handpointer = new ImageView(this);
```

//grab the imageview and load the animations

```
handpointer.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hand));

TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TL.addView(tr1);
tr1.aadView(b1);


TableRow tr2 = new TableRow(this);
tr2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TL.addView(tr2);
tr2.addView(handpointer);

TableRow tr3 = new TableRow(this);
tr3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TL.addView(tr3);
tr3.addView(b2);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Param.setMargins(0, 70, 0, 0);
L1.addView(FrameLayout,Param);

Param.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
FrameLayout.addView(TL,Param);
RelativeParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.snail_menu); 
L1.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

this.setContentView(L1);
```